# How to change the height and width of checkbox in kendo UI angular using css

Tags: ios, css, checkbox, kendo-ui

I am developing first application using kendo UI angular. How to change the height and width of checkbox in kendo UI angular using css?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some default set of CSS properties affecting the checkbox. To give a different style, one needs to add necessary styles to the same element in another CSS file and ensure the second CSS file is rendered in the application. So for example you can try the following:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{

margin: 4px 0 0;
padding: 0;
background-color:#ccc;

}
```

Please let me know if it doesn't work. I will try harder and learn something new! Thanks!